# What about singleton pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I was looking for info about singleton pattern, I found: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#95196

I don't understand:

```
final static public function getInstance()
{
    static $instance = null;

    return $instance ?: $instance = new static;
}
```

If it set $instance to null, why this kind of return? Why do not create $instance in the global "space" of the class without set it to null in getInstance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot initiate class variables with non-static values, so

```
class X {
    $instance = new SomeObj();
}
```

is not permitted.

The code you've posted is one way of going about making sure that only ONE instance of that class is defined.

```
static $instance = null;
```

will create the variable and set it to `null` the first time that method is called. After that, sicne it's been declared `static`, PHP will ignore that line.

Then the other code can be seen as the following:

```
if (isnull($instance)) {
    ... first time through this method, so instantiate the object
    $instance = new someobj;
}
return $instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find following links useful for understanding singleton patterns.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

[PHP Patterns](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/singleton_pattern)

Comment: This does not address the OP's question about this specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, the `$instance` is preceded with the static keyword, inside a function call. This means the variable retain it's state (value) between calls to the function. The nullifing will only happen once, in the initial call to the function.
b.t.w. this is C way of doing singletons...

Comment: Why this is the C way? what is PHP way?

Comment: Well, PHP is both procedural and OO. The above is the procedural way, and very similar in syntax to how you would do it in C.
Take a look in the links you got above, it shows all the modern ways to do it.